# Merge two std::queue

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any function in stl that joins two `std::queue` objects?

Comment: Do you really need to use a queue? If you use an std::list instead you could splice the two lists in constant time (that's assuming that they don't need to be sorted).

Comment: What would it mean to do so? How would entries be ordered in the merged queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::queue` adapter doesn't support iteration so you'd actually have to roll your own method to do this. But given that you need this functionality, you should probably consider a different container. If you need random access, the probably `std::deque`. If you only need front/back access like a queue consider `std::list` which can be `splice`d together in constant time.

Comment: Except using a list will only be beneficial if he splices large lists often, because a list is much slower doing *everything* else.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any options provided in stl, but I can think of some other things you can write yourself:

1. Write your own code to read one queue into another, but this is O(n).
2. Use `std::copy` to manipulate the underlying `std::deque` containers, again O(n).
3. Create your own container which is implemented in terms of `std::queue`, but can maintain multiple queues to simulate a join in O(1).